# Unable to position element to the right

Tags: react-native

I have a few elements on my app screen and I want the last one to be positioned towards the bottom-right (I'm using the Expo client on Android). Here's the `render()` function from `App.js`:

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <StatusBar
                hidden={true}
            />
            <TodoItem/>
            <TodoItem/>
            <TodoItem/>

            <AddTodoButton style={styles.button}/>
        </View>
    );
}
```

So, it's the `<AddTodoButton\>` that I want to position. Here's the styles I'm using:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: '#fcf7e2',
        height: '100%',
    },

    button: {
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: 0,
        right: 0,
    }
});
```

The code for `AddTodoButton` is as follows:

```
const Button = () => (
    <Text style={styles.button}>+</Text>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    button: {
        fontSize: 30,
        paddingLeft: 21,
        paddingTop: 7,
        width: 60,
        height: 60,
        backgroundColor: '#FF4456',
        borderRadius: 60/2,
        overflow: 'hidden',
    }
});
```

I've tried several variations of styles for the `button` property, but the element doesn't respond and is stuck to the left edge right after the three `<TodoItem/>` (which are nothing but `<Text>` as of now).

I'm happy doing this in Flexbox, except that I don't know how to and managed to mess up the layout completely when I tried. :|

Any thoughts?

Comment: can you provide the code of `AddTodoButton `?

Comment: @Coyote Added to my original question. While I did receive an answer that solved it, I'm still adamant on making it work without using `flex`. Please see if you can crack it. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if simply adding `flex:1` to `container` style works, if not try the following

```
render() {
   return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar
            hidden={true}
        />
        <TodoItem/>
        <TodoItem/>
        <TodoItem/>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <AddTodoButton style={styles.button}/>
        </View>
    </View>
   );
}

// In your styles, do the following
container: {
   flex: 1
}

buttonContainer{
  flex: 1,
  flexDirection: 'row',
  justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  alignItems: 'flex-end',
  alignSelf: 'flex-end'
}
```

Not sure about your `AddTodoButton` but I'd recommend looking there to see if that's the one not pushing things to the right.

Comment: Adding `flex:1` to container doesn't work, but wrapping the `AddTodoButton` in a separate view, as you suggested, does work. My question now is, why didn't my original approach work? Is `flex` the only recommended way to position stuff in React Native?

Comment: Yup. It's not HTML. React Native does Flexbox layout so it renders constantly across all devices.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just simply did not apply the style to your button:

```
const Button = (props) => (
   <Text style={[styles.button,props.style]}>+</Text>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    button: {
        fontSize: 30,
        paddingLeft: 21,
        paddingTop: 7,
        width: 60,
        height: 60,
        backgroundColor: '#FF4456',
        borderRadius: 60/2,
        overflow: 'hidden',
    }
});
```

Comment: Good point! But is it a good practice for the parent to pass the styles down?

Comment: if you want to style a child component you must pass a style.